# starting to learn js - login message

Tags: javascript

Well I started just a couple of weeks ago to learn `js`, and now I'm stuck with my code.
I tried to send a message of approval every time a user login something into the input, and send an error message every time the user doesn't write anything and click the login button.

the error is that I keep getting the "Not Good" message every time, no matter what I put in!

How do I improve my code?
Code:

```js
function login(input) {

  var login = checkLogin(input.value);

  if (!login.success) {
    alert(login.error);
    return;
  }
  alert("Success!");
}

function checkLogin(n) {
  if (n.trim().length === 0)
    return {
      success: false,
      error: 'Not good'
    };

  return {
    success: true,
    message: 'Wow'
  };

}
```

```html
Login
<input id="Login" type="text" size: "10">
<button onClick="login(this)">Lets go</button>
```

Comment: What specific error are you encountering?  Also, can you provide your HTML?

Comment: edited the changes

Comment: You spelled "succsess" incorrectly in the checkLogin function.

Comment: Probably one of the most useful things to know about javascript development in a browser environment is the existence of the **Developer Tools** - I think the `F12` key is the way to bring them up in most browsers these days. The most useful part to begin with is the **console** and the **inspector** then probably the **network** tab will become useful as you progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass `this` with the onclick handler you're passing the button object. But what you really want to look at is the input object (with id "Login"). To get the value of that object you need to use `document.getElementById`.

```
function login() {

    var login = checkLogin(document.getElementById("Login").value);

    if(!login.success){
        alert(login.error);
        return;
    }
    alert("Success!");
}

function checkLogin(n) {
    if( n.trim().length === 0)
        return {
            success:false,
            error:'Not good'
        };

    return {
        success:true,
        message:'Wow'
    };

}
```

You can also change the html to the following (there is no need to pass `this`):

```
 Login <input id="Login" type="text" size="10">
 <button onClick="login();"> Lets go </button>
```

As an aside, the way Javascript handles functions is a bit interesting. A function (such as login) is called regardless of the number of parameters it takes and the number of parameters supplied. So calling `login(this)` or `login(1,2,3)` or just `login()` would all call the function defined in `function login()`. If after this code you wrote `function login(oneparam)` this would overwrite the `function login()`. So technically, you could leave your HTML as is, though it would be misleading.